# When investing a settlement, what tax ramifications should be considered?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, pennsylvania, lawsuit-settlement

Let us suppose that someone receives a lump sum settlement from a car accident (personal injury) case and would like to invest it for maximum long-term returns.  We will say that the settlement amount is $100,000.  We will assume that the receiver has a solid understanding of investing and initially plans to put the majority of the amount into mutual funds and commission-free ETFs.  The latter will be used as part of a monthly auto-withdrawal for living expenses.  Occasional trades for redistribution to maintain asset mix.

In determining the viability of this plan, what considerations need made regarding taxation in order to maximize long-term gain?  To clarify the question, things that may come into play might be:

- Tax savings via Roth IRA
- Capital gains tax affects of redistribution trades
- ETFs tax advantages over other investment options
- Other unknowns

Essentially, like many, I am ignorant of much of the tax code around investment, other than the basics required for monthly retirement deposits, and do not want to make a mistake with this settlement.  This question applies to the US tax code, specifically a resident of Pennsylvania.

**Further Information**

I'd like to expand upon the above question with further assumptions and restrictions:

- Initial investment is $100,000, but a future larger settlement is possible and expected
- No other income source can reasonably be expected in the future
- Withdrawals will be expected to be less than appreciation
- For the purposes of this question assume that this money will be invested in stocks, bonds, ETFs, mutual funds, or similar
- This person has no other investment accounts
- Net income is/was $23k annually
- Investor is not married, but lives with a domestic partner and children and may one day marry

Comment: What is the person's age?  When do they plan to retire?  Are you saying they will use none of the money to live on in the short term?

Comment: Good questions.  Assume the age is mid 30s.  Assume that they will not be able to work in the foreseeable future and will pull out a monthly sum for living expenses.

Comment: @Nicholas - adding some remaining missing bits would help. Do they have any other savings? About how much is their income now? From what I read so far, taxes are the least of my concern.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is not the best situation.  Sorry to your friend.

First off ROTHs are out, you need earned income.  Secondly, I don't think the focus should be on retirement planning until there is again an earned income.  Thirdly, this person is just in a bad spot.

Lets assume that you can find some really good mutual funds, that consistently return 10% per year.  At best this person can only pull out 10K per year without touching principle.  At that income level, taxes are not much of a concern; not as much as surviving.  If this person knows anything about investing, they know funds don't work like this.  They could be down 5%, down 5%, up ~40% in three years to give an average of 10% return.  Which of course further complicates matters.

This person (IMO) should seek to start a different career.  One that can cater to any long term issues this person has with pain/disability.  The money could be used toward training/education in order to get money flowing again.  That is not to say the full amount should be used for a BA in Russian Folk Literature, but some minimum training to get a career that starts earning real money.

Comment: I wonder how well your first sentence translates for our non English speakers.

Answer (score -4):

the $5500 Roth IRA is not restricted to earned income, you can put whatever money you have tax free and gains free.

Comment: Hey Kevmolio, I believe this statement is wrong. Can you provide a link to back it up?